# ¿Por qué no se ve una imagen.jpg que paso como prop?

Tags: reactjs

No encuentro el motivo por el cual la imagen que paso como prop en el componente no se ve en el navegador.

A la imagen la tengo en la carpeta *images*, al mismo nivel que la carpeta *src*. He probado cambiar la imagen a la carpeta *public* y tampoco sale.

Lo que he probado:

```
import { useState } from "react";

const ImageComponent = ({ src, alt, message }) => {
  const [showMessage, setShowMessage] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setShowMessage(true);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <img src={src} alt={alt} onClick={handleClick} />
      {showMessage && <div>{message}</div>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ImageComponent;
```

Luego, lo vuelco en mi page que se llama *CuriositiesPage*:

```
import ImageComponent from "../components/ImageComponent";

export const CuriositiesPage = () => {
  return (
    <main>
      <Link to="/curiosities">
        <h1>Curiosidades</h1>

        <section>
          <ImageComponent
            src={`./images/conejozanahoria.jpg`}
            alt={`Conejito`}
            message={
              "Los conejos tienen dientes que crecen constantemente, por lo que necesitan masticar constantemente para mantenerlos limados. Además, los conejos pueden saltar muy alto y correr a una velocidad de hasta 50 kilómetros por hora."
            }
          />
        </section>
```

He probado a cambiar la imagen a la carpeta *public* y tampoco sale. También he probado:

```
import gatosaltando from "../images/gatosaltando.jpg";
<section>
          <ImageComponent
            src={`url(${gatosaltando})`}
            alt={`Gato Saltando`}
            message={
              "Los gatos son capaces de saltar hasta seis veces su longitud corporal y aterrizar de manera segura en sus pies. Esto se debe a una columna vertebral muy flexible y una habilidad para girar sus patas mientras están en el aire."
            }
          />
        </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta creando una carpeta public a nivel de src, y mete ahi las imagenes, y al acceder a esta carpeta no uses rutas relativas, los compiladores usualmente usan la carpeta public como ruta absoluta:

```
public > images > ️image.jpg
```

si tienes algo asi, la ruta seria de este tipo

```
'/images/image.jpg'
```

Answer (score 0):

Este error es comun al inicio, react se renderiza en el archivo `index.html` que esta en la carpeta public por eso al poner ese `path` no encuentra el archivo, la mejor manera es importar la imagen con js de esta manera:

```
import ImageComponent from "../components/ImageComponent";
import Image from "./images/conejozanahoria.jpg"

export const CuriositiesPage = () => {
  return (
    <main>
      <Link to="/curiosities">
        <h1>Curiosidades</h1>

        <section>
          <ImageComponent
            src={Image}
            alt={`Conejito`}
            message={
              "Los conejos tienen dientes que crecen constantemente, por lo que necesitan masticar constantemente para                       mantenerlos limados. Además, los conejos pueden saltar muy alto y correr a una velocidad de hasta 50                           kilómetros por hora."
            }
          />
        </section>
```

De esta manera la direccion de la imagen se renderiza junto con react, algunos agregan las imagenes en la carpeta public y hacen referencia directa como `/images/image.jpg`, pero esto en ocaciones genera problemas.

Espero te haya servido amiga!!